How does Joomla Generate a Page When the View is Excluded?
I've been trying to resolve a really annoying bug, and I've tracked it down to a convention of writing JRoute code that looks like this: JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login')
This will generate a URL like: /component/users/?task=user.login
Note that the view is missing! But for whatever reason, if I submit the login form and it points to that URL, it still logs me in. How does it work without a view?
Background
I'm having a bug where this code does NOT work on my site, so login with the core login component gives an error like 0 - Invalid controller: name='user', format=''
Unfortunately it's really hard to debug because it only happens when going through a WAF (Sucuri) and when the Sec-Ch-Ua headers are included which they unfortunately are in Chrome! I'm hoping to understand at a deeper level why the above URL even works in the first place, so I can try to understand why it doesn't work in this specific case.

Do you have 'Search Engine Friendly URLs' set to Yes in the configuration and 'Use URL Rewriting' set to Yes ? Try setting them to No and see if it changes the response.

@Irata I can't switch this unfortunately in the live environment, but I can test the index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login url directly by modifying the login form with dev tools, so I just did, and it worked without the view! So that works, but /component/users/?task=user.login gives the error. I can add the view to that SEF URL and it still gives the error so I guess it has nothing to do with the view...

@Irata also, /component/users/ is a totally valid URL that loads the login form normally. It's only by adding ?task=user.login that it errors out inexplicably with the SEF url but not the direct url. It's really weird. Anyway I feel closer now, thanks for the prompt.

Displaying a view is really executing display task of the main controller. Therefore, view parameter is only specific to display task, it is not used by other controllers/tasks. Core components are written to default to this task so adding it to the URL is not necessary. Otherwise, the URL for displaying a view would look like this:
index.php?option=com_example&task=display&view=someview

Other controllers normally do not render views. They execute whatever logic they need and then perform a redirect or throw an exception.
